# Why it is only adding last element of arraylist? or Possible solution?

Tags: java

In first loop I am looping through variable rgname which is [Monthly,Quarterly,Yearly]. Now,I created another method called listDir. If I pass variable value here folder = new File(reportFolderPath + reportPath + "/"+ rgname); and later to the method listDir it will return list of array like as shown below.

```
           List<ReportGroup> reportGroupList = new ArrayList<ReportGroup>();
            for (String rgname : reportGroupNames) {
                ReportGroup rg = new ReportGroup();
                rg.setReportGroupName(rgname);// Report Name such as
                                                // Monthly,Quarterly and
                                                // Yearly

                folder = new File(reportFolderPath + reportPath + "/"+ rgname);

                List<ReportInfo> reportList = new ArrayList<ReportInfo>();
                List<String> reportDescription=listDir(folder);

                for(String reportDescr:reportDescription){
                    System.out.println("*****************Test***************" +reportDescr);
                    rg.setReportDescr(reportDescr);
                }  
                    rg.setReportList(reportList);

                reportGroupList.add(rg);

            report.setReportGroupList(reportGroupList);
        }
    }
```

Second Method returns the arraylist:

```
    public static List<String> listDir(final File folder) {

    List<String> dirArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (final File fi : folder.listFiles()) {

        if (fi.isDirectory()) {

            dirArray.add(fi.getName());
        }
    }

    return dirArray;
}
```

The Output should be like this:

```
     Monthly
           -Jan
           -Feb 
           -Continue
    Quarterly
           -First Quarter
           -Second continue
```

Second method returns this value and this is what it prints when doing System.out.println(reportDescription);

```
       [539_January_2013, 540_February_2013, 541_March_2013, 542_April_2013, 543_May_2013, 544_June_2013, 545_July_2013, 546_August_2013, 547_September_2013, 548_October_2013, 549_November_2013, 550_December_2013, 587_January_2014]

       [551_First_Quarter_2013, 554_Second_Quarter_2013, 557_Third_Quarter_2013, 560_Fourth_Quarter_2013]

       [123_Year_2010]
```

Comment: I tried that ,I put system out and I see only one record which is last element.

Comment: Where are you printing output?

Comment: Can you provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: I am passing values such as monthly ,quarterly etc to rgName Variable folder = new File(reportFolderPath + reportPath + "/"+ rgname), later it goes to the second methos and return arraylist like jan,feb,mar etc

Comment: @Betlista I am printing right after the second loop.

Comment: Well, this `rg.setReportDescr(reportDescr);` sounds like a simple setter method, that will overwrite the former content.

Comment: @Tom Even before that when I loop the array list it will only print last element of the array but not the entire list.

Comment: Which loop? This one: `for(String reportDescr:reportDescription)`? If it only prints the last element, how do you know, that it contains more than that?

Comment: Here is how I am calling the method List<String> reportDescription=listDir(folder); which returns the list like this [jan,feb,mar,april.....dec]. Then looping the returned value (String reportDescr:reportDescription)

Comment: ok, in your output was nothing like `***Test***` if there is just one `***Test***` printed, there is just one element in `reportDescription` list, simple as that. Add `System.out.println(reportDescription.size())` before the loop...

Comment: Or just `System.out.println(reportDescription);`. This prints the content of the whole list.

Comment: @Tom I just did that, and as result there are multiple arrays printed as you can see in last code snippet(just updated). That's what it prints.

Comment: And then your program ends or what? Add some debugging print statement after the loop, whether it is printed. Last possibility is, that exception is thrown and that's why loop is interrupted...

Comment: And then the loop prints just `587_January_2014`, `560_Fourth_Quarter_2013` or `123_Year_2010`. I still don't know which data you expect and which you actual get.

Comment: @Tom , yes thats what it prints(I think you now understand my problem). I actually wants it to print all the elements.

Comment: But it doesn't make any sense. If you place the `System.out.println(reportDescription)` right above the `for` loop and it contains everything, then it is not possible, that this test print `System.out.println("*Test*" + reportDescr)` only shows the last one.

Comment: @Tom, I just wanted to check if the previous line of code works or not,only for testing.

Comment: Which "previous line"?

Comment: Just to check if this works List<String> reportDescription=listDir(folder);

Comment: And what does that line print? Every element or the last one only?

Comment: @Tom before loop it prints all the elements but after the loop only last element.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65651/discussion-between-tom-and-lokesh).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As found out in the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65651/discussion-between-tom-and-lokesh), the problematic line is this:

```
rg.setReportDescr(reportDescr);
```

As I assumed in the comments before, this *is* a standard setter method which will overwrite the old data with the new one. Therefore the last remaining data is the last element of the list:

```
public void setReportDescr(String reportDescr) {
    this.reportDescr = reportDescr;
}
```

An easy way to fix this, is to pass the whole list to the `ReportGroup` instance:

```
List<String> reportDescriptions=listDir(folder);
rg.setReportDescriptions(reportDescriptions); // changed method name a bit
rg.setReportList(reportList);
reportGroupList.add(rg);
```

In the class `ReportGroup`, the line `String reportDescr;` should be changed to:

```
List<String> reportDescr;
```

And the getter and setter methods should be changed accordingly:

```
public List<String> getReportDescriptions() { // changed method name a bit
    return reportDescr;
}

public void setReportDescriptions(List<String> reportDescr) { // changed method name a bit
    this.reportDescr = reportDescr;
}
```

Comment: Makes lot of sense so it's should be stored as list of data but not as a single element. Thank you so much all of you. Have a good weekend.

Comment: for your patience (+1)

Comment: By doing so,I get an error here rg.setReportDescr(reportDescr); saying The method setReportDescr(List<String>) in the type ReportGroup is not applicable for the arguments (String).

Comment: You've given him a single `String` and not the whole list.

Comment: I did not get ,where? I tried doing this way as well 
    
for(List<String> reportDescr:reportDescription){
               rg.setReportDescr(reportDescr);

Comment: I already changed getter setter methods for List<String>reportDescr;

Comment: Please use the code, I've posted in my answer: `List<String> reportDescriptions=listDir(folder);` and `rg.setReportDescr(reportDescriptions);`. No need for a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

So your modified code is this:

```
System.out.println(reportDescription);
for(String reportDescr:reportDescription){
    System.out.println("*****************Test***************" +reportDescr);
    rg.setReportDescr(reportDescr);
}
```

so it should print something like:

```
   [539_January_2013, 540_February_2013, 541_March_2013, 542_April_2013, 543_May_2013, 544_June_2013, 545_July_2013, 546_August_2013, 547_September_2013, 548_October_2013, 549_November_2013, 550_December_2013, 587_January_2014]
   *****************Test***************587_January_2014
   [551_First_Quarter_2013, 554_Second_Quarter_2013, 557_Third_Quarter_2013, 560_Fourth_Quarter_2013]
   *****************Test***************560_Fourth_Quarter_2013
   [123_Year_2010]
   *****************Test***************123_Year_2010
```

right?

Why you cannot simple add all information?

Comment: I am sorry, Yes you are correct!! Right now it just prints only last element of each member.

Comment: I agree with @Tom, this is not possible, your information are incorrect. Sorry, we cannot help you...

Comment: I may have hard time explaining but only purpose is here to display all the elements of array instead of last element.

Comment: As you mentioned earlier it print like this *****************Test***************587_January_2014, I needed all elements of month not just the last one which is 587_january_2014

Comment: Next time, when you are asked for complete output, paste complete output, not the filtered one, please! Of, course there were all items printed...

Answer (score 1):

Your code is very confusing!

I'm not sure what the goal is here, but it seems like you are overwriting the folder such that only the last month is being printed out. You can try creating a new File each time and adding that to its own list. Then you can iterate through that. Here is some code, although it's not doing what you want it to do, but you can use it to give you an idea of what to do next:

```
    List<String> monthsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    monthsList.add("January");
    monthsList.add("June");
    monthsList.add("December");

    List<File> folderList = new ArrayList<File>();
    for(String month : monthsList)
    {
        File folder = new File("C:\\temp\\"+month);
        if(!folder.exists())
        {
            folder.mkdir();
        }

        folderList.add(folder);
    }

    List<String> dirArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (final File fi : folderList)
    {
        if(fi.isDirectory())
        {
            dirArray.add(fi.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }

    for(String directory : dirArray)
    {
        System.out.println("*****************Test***************\n" + directory);
    }
```

Comment: Can you add System.out.println("Size of directory: " + reportDescription.size()); before ` for(String reportDescr:reportDescription){` <-- this will at the very least check to see if your data is right.